# Extract field from a specific line with reg expressions

Tags: regex

I want to extract the time (the number between "in" and "ms") from the line that contains "Extracted" in the example below.

2022-01-16 13:35:30,591 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-scheduler-worker-1] Committed 1 changes in Java Cache; in 16 ms.
2022-01-16 13:35:27,049 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-rro-226-unique] Heart beat #148000: avgInterval=1007: maxInterval=2360 ms.
2022-01-11 20:28:10,324 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-boot] Extracted archive Archive_ZipFile[D:\Tomcat9054\webapps\ebx_common-resources\configuration\mima\export\MIMA\files\data\Directory_Configuration\Configuration\archives\Configuration.ebx]@26ec4785 in 16 ms.
2022-01-11 20:28:04,120 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-boot] Inserted 174 tableHolders pointing to home 18490 in 0 ms.

I already have the expression to select the line that I want but can't add the condition to extract the number between the two words...

```
^.*\bExtracted\b.*$
```

Would appreciate if anybody can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your expected output from those string ? like the number from those string

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer

```
import re
str = ''' 2022-01-16 13:35:30,591 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-scheduler-worker-1] Committed 1 changes in Java Cache; in 16 ms. 2022-01-16 13:35:27,049 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-rro-226-unique] Heart beat #148000: avgInterval=1007: maxInterval=2360 ms. 2022-01-11 20:28:10,324 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-boot] Extracted archive Archive_ZipFile[D:\Tomcat9054\webapps\ebx_common-resources\configuration\mima\export\MIMA\files\data\Directory_Configuration\Configuration\archives\Configuration.ebx]@26ec4785 in 16 ms. 2022-01-11 20:28:04,120 CET INFO log.persistence 1103:0038 [ebx-boot] Inserted 174 tableHolders pointing to home 18490 in 0 ms.'''

res = re.search(r'(?:Extracted.+?)(?:in\s(\d+)\sms)',str)
res.group(1)
```

Regex Explanation:
`(?: <regex_pattern>)` means non-capturing group

`\s` means whitespace

`\d+` capture digit one or more

`(?:Extracted.+?)` means from 'Extracted' get anything until

Basically get this regex capture 'Extracted' until it finds `in <number> ms` and get the `<number>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the number in the same line, and you don't want to cross matching a dot followed by a space:

```
\bExtracted\b[^.]*(?:\.(?! )[^.]*)*\sin\s+(\d+)\s+ms\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bExtracted\b` Match the word `Extracted` between word boundaries
- `[^.]*` OPtionally match any char except a dot
- `(?:\.(?! )[^.]*)*` Repeat matching a dot not followed by a space and then again any char except a dot
- `\sin\s+` Match `in` between whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `\s+ms\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/71kzyd/1)